# Can same topic be configured to multiple s3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sns, external-tables

I am trying to refresh external table using SNS in snowflake.
I have followed this tutorial to refresh.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCNa3d6rMO0

it is working as expected.but when I use same topic to trigger another table in another S3 bucket. Can't I use the same topic and create event notifications in Bucket2?

Here is my Access Policy :

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:58:snowflake-dev-SNS",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "55"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "__console_pub_0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:55:snowflake-dev-SNS"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::2:user/b6m8-s-p2s9"
      },
      "Action": "sns:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:55:snowflake-dev-SNS"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks,
Xi

Comment: Hello @Xi12. Did you find any solution to use the same topic for multiple S3 buckets?

Comment: No i could create same SNS, created a new Sns

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Snowflake person, but it appears that the linked demonstration is [Configuring Amazon SNS to Automate Snowpipe Using SQS Notifications](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#option-2-configuring-amazon-sns-to-automate-snowpipe-using-sqs-notifications)
.

According to that documentation, the following code is used to create the pipe:

```sql
create pipe snowpipe_db.public.mypipe
  auto_ingest=true
  aws_sns_topic='<sns_topic_arn>'
  as
    copy into snowpipe_db.public.mytable
    from @snowpipe_db.public.mystage
  file_format = (type = 'JSON');
```

The `copy into snowpipe_db.public.mytable` seems to be hard-coded for a destination table. It seems that each Snowpipe can only be used to load data into a **single table**.

Therefore, you would likely need to use a different Snowpipe, and therefore a different SNS Topic and SQS queue, if you wish to load data into a different table.

Comment: Sorry  I am not creating a pipe. I want it to work as a external table

Comment: The linked video shows an Amazon SQS subscription to the Amazon SNS topic [at 11:18](https://youtu.be/PCNa3d6rMO0?t=678) and the endpoint for SQS mentions `snowpipe`.

Comment: Did you added both your bucket locations in your Storage integration object (remember to modify your ARN policy if you are modifying/recreating your storage integration object
)? - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-storage-integration.html#syntax